# How to filter values on a python series

Tags: python, pandas, series

I have a data frame and I saved the first row of this data frame as following

```
first_row = data_model.loc[0,:]
```

If I print out `first_row`, it looks like

```
label                class
wa                     3
not                    0
im                     2
time                   0
see                    2
like                   0
going                  2
amp                    1
get                    1
one                    0
```

I only want to keep values greater then 0, so I use `first_row[first_row > 0]`, but I get an error message like:

> TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'.

If I use `first_row[first_row != 0]`, I will get what I want.

Comment: You can edit the post by clicking the 'edit' button below the questions tags

Comment: your data should be integer, it is string. You cannot compare integers & strings.

Comment: Do you mean "class" stores values as strings?  If that is the case, why 'first_row != 0' works?

Comment: Can you post the output of `first_row.dtype` ?

Comment: it is <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

Comment: Figured out why... The first element in first_row is (label, class), which is reason causing the error. If I remove the first element, I will have no problem apply the filter. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the query function of the DataFrame will return the desired result

```
df=pd.DataFrame({"label:["wa","not","im","time","see","lke","going"],"amp":`[3,0,2,0,2,0,2]})

df=df.query("amp>0")

print(df)

           amp  label
        0    3     wa
        2    2     im
        4    2    see
        6    2  going
```